# Rails cannot load such file on require even though directory is in autoload_paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an exception `LoadError Exception: cannot load such file -- acts_as_versioned` when trying to `require 'acts_as_versioned'`

I have setup a config/initializer with `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib/acts_as_versioned/lib"` which is where acts_as_versioned resides.  I have validated that this path is showing up in autoload_paths at the point in time where it is actually required, but it raises the LoadError exception.

However, if I do a require directly to the path `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/acts_as_versioned/lib/acts_as_versioned"` it works correctly.

---

According to the documentation at

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-availability

Specifically this comment `config.autoload_paths is accessible from environment-specific configuration files, but any changes made to it outside config/application.rb don't have an effect.` I'm lead to believe it may no longer be possible to modify the autoload_paths outside of config.

When I moved the autoload_paths update into config it works fine; I would love to hear though if there is a solution that doesn't require this as I would much prefer having my paths set within my initializers rather than setting all of them in the config.

Comment: A sanity check: did you restart Rails?

Comment: Are you not using the gem? You should not need to manually autoload the files if so.

Comment: @BradJohnson No; I am not using a gem.  This is an old legacy Rails application from the days of plugins.  We are not able to upgrade to a gem version of acts_as_versioned currently; so I'm going the route of moving it into lib while we upgrade from Rails 3 to Rails 4.  The long term goal would be to get back onto the main gem, but definitely not an option before we finish the upgrade.